# Dynamically return a file based on query argument

Tags: wiremock

I have this stub defined within my mappings directory. I'm trying to return a file dynamically based upon the value of my query parameter (the query param and file name will have the same name)

Please see below an example.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/some/url/locales/en_GB/products",
    "queryParameters": {
      "typeName": {
        "matches": "([A-Za-z]*)"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "{{request.pathSegments.[5]}}",
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}
```

The GET request would look something like

```
.../some/url/locales/en_GB/products?typeName=blah
```

In my __files directory, I would have a file called blah.json which I want the response to match.

I'm not sure if the `bodyFileName` is correct. The 5 represents positioning of the query param, zero-indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figuring out what values are represented by the different Response Template variables is not difficult. Below is an example to g

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/some/url/locales/en_GB/products",
    "queryParameters": {
      "typeName": {
        "matches": "([A-Za-z]*)"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body" : "request.requestline.pathSegments:\n[0]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[0]}}\n[1]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[1]}}\n[2]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[2]}}\n[3]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[3]}}\n[4]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[4]}}\n[5]: {{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[5]}}\n\nrequest.query.typeName: {{request.query.typeName}}",
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}
```

And a GET request `http://localhost:8080/some/url/locales/en_GB/products?typeName=test` results in this response:

```
request.requestline.pathSegments:
[0]: some
[1]: url
[2]: locales
[3]: en_GB
[4]: products
[5]: 

request.query.typeName: test
```

With the above in mind you can see that the value you seek is not retrieved using `request.pathSegments[x]` but rather `request.query.typeName`. This results then into:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/some/url/locales/en_GB/products",
    "queryParameters": {
      "typeName": {
        "matches": "([A-Za-z]*)"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "{{request.query.typeName}}.json",
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Unfortunately, still, no luck using request.query.typeName. 

Not sure if it's related but I am running wiremock inside a docker container. 

This is the exception I am seeing when calling the wiremock service from a browser.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/wiremock/./__files/{{request.query.typeName}}.json (No such file or directory)

Comment: Do you have the `response-template` transformer applied to that WireMock rule? To me it seems it looks for exactly the string: `./__files/{{request.query.typeName}}.json` and did not replace  `{{request.query.typeName}}` with whatever you provided in the URL.

Comment: Thanks A.Kootstra. A little confusion with the documentation. I thought I had the transformer enabled by passing it within the response as shown above. But it actually needed to be passed as a command argument in the docker-compose.yml to the container. Once passing --global-response-templating it worked fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: image: rodolpheche/wiremock
    command:
      - "--verbose"
      - "--global-response-templating"
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"